# Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada) no YACC/Bison

Tags: bison

ERRO ao fazer printf de inteiros
Quando tento entrar com o texto : ESCREVER 10;
                                  TERMINAR;
aparece o erro de Falha de segmentação (imagem do núcleo gravada) , uma vez que o lista é tipo string e não consigo fazer o printf de inteiros.

Segue o codigo YACC/BISON:

```
%{

 #include <stdio.h>
 int yylex(void);
 int yyerror(const char *s);
 char stR[20];


%}
%union{
    char *str; /* para strings*/
    int num; /* para inteiros */
     }

%token TERMINAR ESCREVER
%token SUBTRACAO 
%token MULTIPLICACAO 
%token DIVISAO 
%token SOMA
%token<num> NUM 
%token<str> TEXTO 
%type<str> elemento
%type<num> expr 
%type<str> lista
%start s

%%

s:linha s
 |TERMINAR ';' {return 0;}
 ;

linha: ESCREVER lista ';' {printf("%s",$2);}                       
     | VARS
     ;

lista: elemento { $$=$1; }
     |lista ',' elemento 
     ;

elemento:TEXTO { $$=$1; }
        |expr  
        ;

VARS :
     | NUM 
     | TEXTO
     | expr
     | TEXTO '=' VARS ';' /* para delcaracoes */
     ;



 expr     : NUM  SOMA expr                {$$=$1+$3;}
          | NUM  SUBTRACAO expr           {$$=$1-$3;}
          | NUM  MULTIPLICACAO expr       {$$=$1*$3;}
          | NUM  DIVISAO expr             {$$=$1/$3;}
          | NUM  '+' expr                 {$$=$1+$3;}
          | NUM  '=' expr                 {$$=$1=$3;}
          | NUM  '-' expr                  {$$=$1-$3;}
          | NUM  '*' expr                 {$$=$1*$3;}
          | NUM  '/' expr                  {$$=$1/$3;}
          | NUM                           {$$=$1;   }
          ;             


%%
```

Codigo LEX

```
 %{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "gram.h"

int yyerror(const char *s);

%}





%%

 "ESCREVER" {return   ESCREVER; }                                
 "TERMINAR" {return TERMINAR; }

  [0-9]+     { yylval.num =atoi(yytext);
               return NUM; }


  [A-Za-z0-9]* { yylval.str=strdup(yytext);
                 return TEXTO;}

"/" |
"-" |
"+" |
"*" |
"=" |
"." |
";" |
","         {return yytext[0]; }
[ \n\t]     {  }
.           { return yytext[0]; }


%%


int yywrap(){ return 1; }
```

Comment: Falta incluir o seu lexer (e quais comandos você usa pra compilar).

Comment: já submeti. o nome do meu programa é pro

gcc -o pro lex.c gram.c, 
gram.c gram.h: pro.y, 
bison -d -o gram.c pro.y,  
lex.c: pro.l gram.h, 
flex -o lex.c pro.l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra começar, é preciso entender a causa do erro. QUando você passa a entrada`ESCREVER 10; TERMINAR;` ela ser;a parseada da seguinte forma:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada um dos nós dessa árvore corresponde a uma regra de redução que será executada. O problema é que para a regra `elemento: expr` você não definiu nenhuma regra então o valor de `$$` vai ficar não inicializado. Mais acima, a regra do `linha` vai interpretar esse valor não inicializado como um ponteiro para string e tentar dar um printf nele, e tudo acaba explodindo.

Pra consertar isso, você vai ter quer dar uma mexida meio grande nas coisas, já que tem muito que obviamente não tem como funcionar na forma atual. O primeiro grande problema é que você disse que `elemento` sempre produz uma string mas o correto seria que elementos possam ser strings ou inteiros. Você pode fazer isso usando uma struct que contém uma union e uma tag dizendo qual dos campos da union está sendo usado:

```
typedef enum { TAG_INT, TAG_STR } Tag;


typedef struct {
    Tag tag;
    union {
      int intval;
      char* strval;
    } u;
} Elemento;
```

Ai na hora de processar os elementos você preenche esses campos apropriadamente:

```
elemento:
      TEXTO {
       $$.tag = TAG_STR;
       $$.u.strval = $1;
     }

    | expr {
       $$.tag = TAG_INT;
       $$.u.intval = $1;
      }
    ;
```

E na hora de imprimir um valor você usa a tag pra saber o que tem que ser feito:

```
 switch(val.tag){
     case TAG_INT:
        printf("%d\n", val.u.intval);
        break;
     case TAG_STR:
        printf("%d\n", val.u.strval);
        break;
     default:
        assert(0);
 }
```

Outro problema que chama a atenção é que você disse que a regra `lista` produz uma string. O correto seria dizer que essa regra produz uma lista de elementos. Acho que a forma mais simples de fazer isso seria usando uma lista encadeada.

---

Não garanto que o código que eu escrevi vá funcionar de primeira (talvez eu tenha feito uma cagada com a sintaxe do C ou yacc) mas a idéia básica é essa.

Comment: e como altero a lista para ser uma lista de elementos tipo %TOKEN <string,int>lista , mas isso não é possível no bison

Comment: Crie um tipo de dados novo `ListaDeElemento`, da mesma forma que criamos um tipo novo `Elemento` pra armazenar um valor que pode ser número ou string.

Comment: queres que eu crie um novo <pre><code>ListaDeElemento:'